# Why doesn't anything happen when I click this submit button?

Tags: css, forms

I am having trouble creating an image submit button.  When I click on it, nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
<input type="image" src="notify_me.png" name="submit" id="submit" OnClick="this.disabled = true" value=""/>

if($_POST) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit the form at the click event:

```
<input type="image" src="notify_me.png" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" />
```

You should also use the input of type submit:

```
<input type="submit" style="width:(width); height:(height); background-image:url('notify_me.png'); border:none; padding:0;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return true after your disable onClick event.

```
<input type="image" src="notify_me.png" name="Submit" id="submit" onClick="this.disabled = true; return true;" value="" />
```